# Need for Speed Shift becomes slow after reaching Tier 3

Tags: technical-issues, need-for-speed-shift

I have a problem in *NFS Shift*. My main profile worked fine until just after Tier 3, when the game became very slow and buggy. The weird thing is that when I created a new profile with same exact graphics settings the game runs at normal speed and everything.

Win7 x64
i7-2600k
GTX 460 [296.10 driver]
Vertex 2

I've uploaded a video that shows what I've described:

The first part of the video is the slow profile, and the second part is the fast one. What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE]: Solved - for anyone that will encounter the same thing the solution for me was:
I have a ps2 gamepad with adapter that have a driver (speedlink PSX2 to PC Gamepad). iv noticed that when im changing the control in the game to keyboard the problem goes away (ya! the solution is more weird then the prob was :] )

just uninstall the driver and clean install the driver.
enjoy